# Anti Aliasing Three.js / WebGL

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I have an issue with anti aliasing when i spin model with orbiter

i am using

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ 
                preserveDrawingBuffer: true,
                antialias: true });

it is helping but not resolving the issue fully.

[image: antialiasing]

in this position it looks ok:

[image: anti aliasing works]

Does anyone know how to resolve this? or have any idea what else can i try? ( code sample would be appreciated )

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Ok i have added this:

renderer.setPixelRatio(2);

and it has improved a LOT ( see result bellow ), but still shows a bit,

anyone has any other idea suggestion?

[image: improved]

Comment: What browser, version, OS, and GPU are you using?

Comment: @TheJim01 what i built was 3D e-commerce store that allows you to customize product, preview in 3D and then add to Cart, anti aliasing should work on all clients visiting the store to purchase products, is that possible with WebGL ?

Comment: There are conditions where that is not possible. For example, older iOS devices did not support hardware anti-aliasing, and therefore did not have good results (like what you're seeing). You could still use anti-aliasing, but only through other avenues, like post-processing ([FXAA example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=AA#webgl_postprocessing_fxaa)).

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure if this will do the trick but it might be worth a try. 
Using the example below, set your textures anisotropy to the renderers max anisotropy. (i am using the webglrenderer) this should enabel antialiasing on this texture and reduce jagged lines like in the first image.

texture.anisotropy = renderer.getMaxAnisotropy().

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer

Comment: @user9446733 i am using THREE.ObjectLoader(), to load json model, is it possible to iterate trough textures and set this? can you provide a code sample? thank you

Comment: I believe there should a variable on the obejt containing materials (called material or materials), each material holds a map, which isset to the texture. on this texture you could set anisotropy as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Are the lines textures?

If so, I had a simular issue then depending on the camera position not completely on top my texture would get blurry. Maybe this helps for you:

```
texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
```